# algorithm to save states for dynamic programming

Tags: php, c, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here's a question regarding saving states in a problem using dynamic programming.

- Every problem of DP saves results and use them further to reduce computation. Let's say, we calculate function value, `f(x,y)=290` and save it in a 2-D array $save, such that,`$save[x][y]=290`. This can be done when `'f'` is dependent on just a small number of variables (for ex.- only 2 variables x and y in above example). But **what can be done when `'f'` is dependent on say, 10 or 15 variables. Making an array of 10 or 15 dimensions would not be memory efficient.**
- **Another solution** could be that we **concatenate the values of variables**(assuming they are unique) and store them in an associative array, using the string obtained by concatenation as key. But, **concatenation is a time consuming operation**. **So, we have a trade off between memory and time**.

**Is there a way to store states if there are higher number of variables onto which the state depends**? I think there might be some way using OOPS or pointers, but I am not quite able to frame anything. Any suggestions? Every idea is appreciated but solutions concerning **'C'** or **'PHP'** in mind, are preferred. I know 'C' doesn't deal with associative arrays but **I just want an algorithm/way to save states.**

Comment: Erm, using a `map:Tuple->Value` ? However, if you are going to calculate ALL possible inputs (x_1,x_2,..x_k) up to some limit - multidimensional array is probably the best solution (Faster access then a `map`, and you are going to fill the map anyway if you calculate all/most values).

Comment: You should reformat this question to make it more readable. No paragraphs and a bunch of bold text is really hard to read.

Comment: @amit I have tried doing it with a 10 dimensional array for k=10 but it takes really high memory. Can you suggest a better solution?

Comment: @verdesmarald I have done that. Thanks.

Comment: Use a hash of the vars as a key, and store function and vars in 1:n tables?

Comment: @JvdBerg Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Saving states in sparsed data is commonly done using a [`map`
   (Associative Array)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) interface. Though C doesn't have it built in -  the internet is full of libraries that offer this functionality.
2. If You are going to compute most/all (x1,...,xk) values anyway - the usage of a `map` is discouraged - it will be slower and won't save memory (the other way around for these cases, actually). If this is the case - a multidimensional array is probably the best solution.
3. Many times in DP, you don't need an array of *all* so far information, just the "line" previously calculated, and override the array. Effectively - for many DP problems that require k*N tables, you actually only need tables of size 2*N, and override the same lines iteratively. The same principle can hold for any dimension I believe - if all you need is the data from previous line, and not all the data.

Comment: you mean, save in a multi-dimensional array and override iteratively?

Comment: @user1708762: Exactly - it is a common optimization in DP algorithms that always requires only the last line and not all of the lines calculated so far.

Comment: thanks. Btw, this optimization is only for bottom up approaches or also for top-down approaches?

Comment: @user1708762: I've never seen it in top-down approaches, and I cannot think of a scenario it will work for in top-down. However - it is perfect for many buttom-up algorithms such as LCS

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please answer the other question asked by me->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655593/minimum-sum-required-to-make-xor-of-some-integers-to-zero